# Slim 3 Conditional route

Tags: php, frameworks, slim

I ran in to a wall, and now my head hurts.

There is this route that returns data to a user.

```
 $this->get('/getdata', 'DataController:SweetData');
```

Controller does its thing and returns data, I am trying to route this single route to different controllers based on a condition.

For example if the user is coming from a specific IP address i want him to use a different controller.
I was thinking of something like this:

```
 $this->get('/getdata', function ($request, $response) {
   ** DO SOME CONDITIONAL MAGIC AND SEND IT TO CONTROLLER ** 
 };
```

My problem is, Im not sure how to send it to different controllers after conditional magic.

Thanks.

Comment: Never worked with Slim v3 but I guess you could use a [middleware](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/concepts/middleware.html) to add an attribute to the Request to use it later, maybe ?

Comment: @AymDev hmm you might be on the right track. I could redirect from within the middleware. Im just curious if it would cause any issues on the client end of things.

Comment: Do you want to actually _redirect_ user to another url? Or do you want to send different responses based on some condition? Or do you want to always use the same controller, but under some specific condition do something prior to invoking controller method?

Comment: @Nima I want to use different controllers based on the outcome of the condition.

Comment: Slim provides support for "sub-request". But this is not a very elegant solution for it. Are you trying to share some code logic? If yes, then Service classes would be a "better" option.

Answer (score 0):

Better practice would be to adopt a pattern of `Route` > `Controller` > `Service` > `Model`. You can skip models if you want, but it's a great way to reuse code and adhere to the DRY principal (don't repeat yourself).

I'd say your head hurts because you are overstepping the bounds of your controller. The controller is just that, the controller -- that's where you should be defining your 'conditional magic'.

In general, I'd recommend you keep your controllers light -- use them to simply collect query parameters, verify valid request bodies, and call an appropriate service. Your main business logic should live within your services. Use models to share common re-usable code between your services.

`/src/Routes/MyRoute.php`:

```php
<?php

use MyApp\Controllers\MyController;

$app->get('/getdata', [MyController::class , 'sweetData']);
```

`/src/Controllers/MyController.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace MyApp\Controllers;

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use MyApp\Services\MyService;
use MyApp\Services\OtherService;

class MyController
{
    protected $myService;
    protected $otherService;

    public function __construct(MyService $myService, OtherService $otherService)
    {
        $this->myService = $myService;
        $this->otherService = $otherService;
    }

    public function sweetData(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        # perform your conditional magic and call your appropriate service

        $someParam = (string)$request->getQueryParam("something");
        if ($someParam === "apple") {
            return $response->withJson($this->myService->doSomething($someParam));
        }
        elseif ($someParam === "orange") {
            return $response->withJson($this->otherService->doSomething($someParam));
        }
    }
}
```

`/src/Services/MyService.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace MyApp\Services;

class MyService
{
    public function doSomething(string $data)
    {
        # $data would be "apple"
        return "Apples are delicious.";
    }
}
```

`/src/Services/OtherService.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace MyApp\Services;

class OtherService
{
    public function doSomething(string $data)
    {
        # $data would be "orange"
        return "Oranges are delicious.";
    }
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I need to follow that pattern. It was a long day and a lot of pressure. I found a solution without overstepping the controllers.